# respond_with not working in ruby on rails. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I have a post method called join that should do the following:
1) create a new object
2) respond with a json object

Here is my code:

```
class GameController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def join
    @p = Player.new(:name => params[:name])
    @p.save!
    respond_with({:uuid => @p.uuid})
  end
end
```

For some reason, the respond_with call always fails with this error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

If I change the respond_with call to something simpler I still get errors, eg:

```
respond_with "hello"
```

yields this error:

```
undefined method `hello_url' for #<GameController:0x1035a6730>
```

What am I doing wrong?? I just want to send them a JSON object back!

PS, my routes file looks like this:

```
  match 'join' => 'game#join', :via => :post
```

Comment: You're better off ditching `respond_with` and just using plain old `format.json { render :json } ` etc. if you want to depart from the standard controller actions.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the `respond_with` methods requires you to pass the resource (`@p`) as an argument.  Here is [some documentation for the method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb#L196-234).

Try this:

```
respond_with @p, :only => [:uuid]
```

You could also render json like this:

```
render :json => { :uuid => @p.uuid }
```

Comment: I actually ended up using render :json, this worked much better on a consistent basis.

Answer (score 4):

Also would work `respond_with {:uuid => @p.uuid}, :location => nil`